# Create an order from an existing order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-quote, create-order

I have seen lot of posts, but didn't get proper answer to create new order from an existing orders at magento.

Concept is create an order from an existing orders by copying all elements/object from of that existing. There are no depends on cart session model or quote.

Have seen that recurring profile have that type concept ?

Can any one give me a solution for create  order from existing  order ?

Comment: You can try by making script, taking current required order data from old order and programatically create new order.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a `reorderAction()` in the controller `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController`. That action actually does exactly what you want to do so you can either redirect to that action or copy and adapt the logic within your own custom model.

Comment: @AmitBera did this answer help you? It's exactly the functionality you were looking for.